Some really good books and notes on operating system and computer networks
I am currently in a tier 3 college . I have a knack for problem solving and things like hft and quant trading interests me a lot.
Now the problem is I am a self learner and donot quite depend on the college professors. So to get into a hft firm , it is said one has to be very good in operating system and computer networks.
Can anyone suggest some books or any resource material which will give me the knowledge and problem solving ability that the very best and intelligent students in the world have .
I would appreciate if the book has very difficult questions on it and some solid theories too.

I assume hft is "high frequency trading". I doubt that any decent book on operating systems or computer networks would focus on that, specifically, or on "quant".

Still how can I be very good , like the very best student in cse from the reputed institutes ?@Buffy. I just want to be on the top of my game so that is why any good book (very good problems or theories ) on os would help.

From where can I get such knowledge @njuffa? I want to know some platform or resources like books to develop my knowledge.

@njuffa thanks for the advice. I will note it down.

What is a tier 3 college? Please provide a bit more context here. This may sound unrelated, but writing well is the best way to be on the top of your game. Take the time to craft well-written questions with plenty of context--your readers don't know anything about your background, experience and knowledge, and as such, it's tough to make a recommendation.

@ggorlen I am sorry for the confusion. So a tier 3 college means a college which does not provide quality education.

Thanks, I was able to infer that, but it's still pretty hard to understand the full context behind the question here. What is your baseline knowledge of the subject? "...which will give me the knowledge and problem solving ability that the very best and intelligent students in the world have" is a rather high expectation to have for a book recommendation.
